# yocto - how to reset image so I can rerun post-install steps

Tags: yocto

I've been handed an SD card which has a yocto image. I know the image had post-install steps, which involved talking to other peripherals on a PCB. I want to be able to "reset" the image so that I can put the SD card into another PCB and have the post-install steps run again.

Is there an easy way to do is or can someone give me a clue as to where I should start looking?

Fyi, I'm currently looking into obtaining a build host so I can try and build a clean image but it would be must easier if I could just "clear a flag" or something just as easy.

Comment: Which manufacturer/model of your board PCB?

Comment: It's completely bespoke.